# Self-referencing primary key on insert

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

When I insert a new record and it auto generates an auto identity value. I then have to subsequently update a column in the same table with that same id that was generated on initial insert. The only way i can see this being accomplished is to first save, get the new PK and then do an update. However is there any other way this can be accomplished in 1 database call? I know I can accomplish this with a stored procedure rather easily, but I don't have that option at this point. See table structure below.

Person
PersonID Int (Auto Identity)
FirstName
LastName
HeadOfHouseholdID int (FK to PersonID) in this table

Comment: I don't think you can do it with a single call (unless you can use a stored proc/insert trigger/etc, which you said you can't). Given you need to set the field, be sure to wrap the calls in a transaction so if either fail, the record doesn't insert. begin transaction --> save record (insert) --> modify record --> save record (update) --> commit transaction

Comment: There is no need for that information to be stored, Simple rule will do the same: if the HeadOfHouseHoldID is null get the PersonID

Comment: @SirRufo Not my design and cant modify the database at all. They are using the column in a view and it must be populated in order for it work. Its a odd scenario.

Comment: @AndrewP Yes I think that is the only way, but just thought i would get an opinion

Answer (score 0):

> is there any other way this can be accomplished in 1 database call?

A trigger or custom SQL query would work.  But it's probably not worth worrying about.